# UICollectionView - iOS 10 - crash on iPhone 6 Plus simulator but works on real device

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, ios10

I've created an UICollectionView that works fine on small devices like iPhone 5s/SE/6/6s/7 on both simulator and real device, but I have a strange situation when it comes about iPhone 6Plus, iPhone 7Plus and any iPad version. It works fine on real device, but it crashes in simulator with the following error:

> Assertion failure in -[_UIFlowLayoutSection
>   computeLayoutInRect:forSection:invalidating:invalidationContext:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UIFlowLayoutSupport.m:823
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UICollectionViewFlowLayout internal error'

What I found out so far is that if I remove the estimatedItemSize it works fine but the auto-layout doesn't anymore, but if I have that enabled it crashes in simulator.

I am using the latest Xcode version and iOS 10.

Any ideas why it's crashing?

Comment: did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498503/collectionviewcontentsize-in-ios-10-using-self-sizing-cells

Comment: very strange. have you tried clearing the DerivedData folder?

Comment: @PrafulD yes but I do not have that case

Answer (score 30):

Calling `invalidateLayout` before layout is a workaround for this issue.

In a `UIViewController` subclass:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

or in a `UIView` subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: Is this considered to be a bug from Apple, or are we doing something wrong? This whole thing was working for me, as long as I used a `UICollectionViewController`, once switching to `UIViewController`, I got this error :-/

Comment: IMO, it's a bug of UIKit. If you support iOS 10, you need to workaround the bug.

Comment: Thanks, your answere saved my day. It's working perfectly fine without the workaround in iOS 11, but for iOS 10 you need to call invalidateLayout()

Comment: Works for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> This is some strange bug in iOS10 with iPhone Plus devices only. I've
>   faced the same issue, my solution was to call layoutIfNeeded like
>   this:
>
> ```
> func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
>     collectionView.layoutIfNeeded() // Patch: only to solve UIKit crash on Plus models
>     return 1
> }
> ```
>
> Doing the same thing in different UICollectionViewDataSources methods
>   will work as well

Answer that worked for me based on **orxelm**'s answer on [collectionViewContentSize in iOS 10 using self-sizing cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498503/collectionviewcontentsize-in-ios-10-using-self-sizing-cells)

Invalidating the layout seemed to prevent my collectionView from using my flow layout, and instead used the default layout. This forced all my cells to be the same size which was not the desired outcome (for me anyway).

Comment: thnx it has fixed the crash in iPhone plus running iOS 10

Comment: happy to help :)