# iOS 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout internal error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view inside self-sizing tableview. When user tap on collection view, I present another view.

I can still present that view in portrait orientation. But when I rotate to landscape, I got this error and crash. How shall I do?

> 2017-01-23 16:52:16.448417 SWEET Mini[1638:647130] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[_UIFlowLayoutSection
>   computeLayoutInRect:forSection:invalidating:invalidationContext:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.6.22/UIFlowLayoutSupport.m:823
>   2017-01-23 16:52:16.451537 SWEET Mini[1638:647130] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UICollectionViewFlowLayout internal error'

I just present another view like this.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    browser.zoomPhotosToFill = NO;
    [browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:(indexPath.row)];
    browser.enableSwipeToDismiss = YES;
    UINavigationController *browseNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:browser];

    if ([[AppDelegate instance].window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) [AppDelegate instance].window.rootViewController;
        [nav presentViewController:browseNav animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if ([[AppDelegate instance].window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *) [AppDelegate instance].window.rootViewController;
        [tab presentViewController:browseNav animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your views hierarchy get corrupted? Why you not use [self presentViewController:browseNav animated:YES completion:nil]; to present another vc ?

Comment: coz i have written that code in NSObject and it is far from uiviewcontroller. (i mean i can still push with delegate)

Comment: Did you tried with delegate? Problem still occurs ?

Comment: You may find help in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467194/584405. In essence, call collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() in the viewWillLayoutSubviews of the viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same error message. Turns out, it's only happening on the simulator, everything works fine on real device.

Comment: For me it was the other way around -.- 
But https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467194/584405 solved it for me.